# Не работает explode

Tags: php, ajax, json

Здравствуйте, есть такой метод в php. Приходит json строка ajaxом($display_months). В цикле я перебираю месяц, и хочу его разбить по пробелу. Но explode не работает.

```
public function sendReportToSingleUser()
    {

        $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
        $display_months=rawurldecode($_POST['display_months']);
        $display_months_new= json_decode($display_months);
        $display_dates=json_decode($_POST['display_dates']);

        //$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('report', 'AuditModel');

        //$result=$model->createCsvSingleUser($user_id,  $display_months, $display_dates);
       // print_r($display_months_new);

        foreach($display_months_new as $month){
            $new_month=explode(' ', $month);
            var_dump($new_month)."<br/>";
        }
    }
```

В консоли Google Chrome отображается вот такое:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "December 2017"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "January 2018"
}
```

Пробовал поставить в разделитель пробел - ' '-результат один и тот же. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: P.S. пробел вырезал редактор - я имею в виду неразрывный пробел(мнемонику)

Comment: Выведите то, что тут( "json_decode($display_months)") через var_dump

Comment: array(12) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "December 2017"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "January 2018"}

Comment: Попробуйте так: `$new_month=preg_split("/[\s]+/", $month);`

Comment: Так не работает. Решил вот так  $new_month=preg_split('/\W/', $month);

Answer (score 1):

```
Решил вот так $new_month=preg_split('/\W/', $month);
```

Приходила не буква или цифра,а другой символ